# Change value of a param in the midst of a function

Tags: function, powershell, switch-statement, string-formatting

Trying to create a PowerShell function that will output a single-line of text using multiple sets of fore and back colors. I have a switch that defines the color sets.

The function has one param that defines the switch value and another param that, if I can get this working, defines the next color set using the same switch:

```
    function Write-Custom
    {
        param($Say,$ThenSay,$Level,$ExtraLevel)
        switch([array]$level)
        {
            none {$c = 'Black','White'}
            name {$c = 'Cyan','DarkBlue'}
            good {$c = 'White','DarkGreen'}
            note {$c = 'Gray','White'}
            info {$c = 'White','DarkGray'}  
            warn {$c = 'Yellow','Black'}
            fail {$c = 'Black','Red'}
        }
        $s = " $Say"
        $ts = " $ThenSay "
        Write-Host $s -ForegroundColor $c[0] -BackgroundColor $c[1]  -NoNewLine
        Clear-Variable Level
        $Level = $ExtraLevel
        Write-Host $ts -ForegroundColor $c[0] -BackgroundColor $c[1]    
    }

    Write-Custom -Say 'hi there' -Level 'name' -ThenSay 'stranger ' -ExtraLevel 'warn'
```

Can't seem to clear and re-define the $level variable. Seems the output ' hi there ' should have a foreground/background of cyan/darkblue, with the ' stranger ' part being yellow/black....but the whole string comes out cyan/darkblue.

Do I need to create a more elaborate switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke the switch each time to get a different color set. One way to do this is to put a function inside your function e.g.:

```
function Write-Custom
{
    param($Say,$ThenSay,$Level,$ExtraLevel)

    function GetColors([string]$level)
    {
        switch([array]$level)
        {
            none {'Black','White'}
            name {'Cyan','DarkBlue'}
            good {'White','DarkGreen'}
            note {'Gray','White'}
            info {'White','DarkGray'}  
            warn {'Yellow','Black'}
            fail {'Black','Red'}
            default { throw "Unrecognized level $level" }
        }
    }

    $c = GetColors($Level)
    Write-Host " $Say" -ForegroundColor $c[0] -BackgroundColor $c[1]

    $c = GetColors($ExtraLevel)
    Write-Host " $ThenSay " -ForegroundColor $c[0] -BackgroundColor $c[1]
}
```

Comment: Nice. Never occurred to me to create a function inside a function. Thanks!